# How to edit a HDFS group?

Tags: linux, hadoop, permissions, hdfs

I have a standalone cluster for practice purpose. I tried to add the root user to hdfs group by logging in as an HDFS user.

The command I used is:

> hdfs dfs -chown -R root:hdfs /

Now, I am able to access hdfs dfs commands as a root. But I don't know how to delete root from HDFS group. I tried this command as hdfs user:

> hdfs dfs -chown -R hdfs:hdfs /

and

> groups

command as a root user. But root is not added to any other group except for it's Primary group.

**How am I supposed to change it back to the way it was?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `hdfs dfs -chown -R <user>:<group>` you are not adding any user to any group.
Rather you are changing the directory/file permissions recursively from the `/` directory.

I think you can try `hdfs dfs -chown -R hdfs:hdfs /` logged in as `hdfs`. Then it should go back to previous state.

Comment: Related http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/cdh-user/132axfm58s/cdh3u5-non-super-user-cannot-change-owner may help

Comment: I tried `hdfs dfs -chowd -R hdfs:hdfs /` logged in as root but i got the error :-             _chown: changing ownership of '/': User hdfs is not a super user (non-super user cannot change owner)._ However, I was able to do it as HDFS user.

Comment: Thanks man. Much appreciated. My reputation is low so I can't upvote the answer. But it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Groups and users don't physically "exist" in HDFS. They only exist on the local operating system. (Assuming you're not using Kerberos + LDAP).

You didn't add anything. You just changed a metadata tag ownership of an HDFS file path. And if you have ACLs and permissions disabled anyway as part of the default properties, these aren't checked.

The namenode(s) are where you would establish user groups using appropriate `groupadd` and `useradd` commands on the OS, but the root user is part of all *nix groups, so I'm not sure why you'd want to delete it rather than just prevent access.

Comment: I agree that root is a part of all *nix groups. But, by default you can't access hdfs directories if you're logged in as a ROOT. You have to log in as a HDFS user to access hdfs. But when I used _chown_ command, now I can access the hdfs as ROOT also, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: Sure. Though, 1) in a production environment, `root` should never have access to the cluster anyway 2) Hadoop isn't secure by default and the user account you're running doesn't really matter - https://blog.samoylenko.me/2015/05/25/hadoop-without-kerberos-examples/

Comment: That was my exact concern. As root shouldn't be able to access the Production environment. And as I have marked the right answer above yours, I was able to get my production environment back in the previous state. Anyways, I'll read the blog and get back to you. Thanks for the concern and sharing the useful information.